# What is wrong with this statement?

Tags: tensorflow

The traceback of the folowing lines is "syntax error". Why?
What shoyuld I do to fix it?

```
 w1=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3,3,1,20])
 layer=tf.nn.conv2d(input=img,filter=w1,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
```

'img' is a grayscale image (np.array), 1x32x32x1.

However, the following lines works perfectly well:

```
def new_w(shape): 
return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev=0.05))
```

and then:

```
   w1=new_w(shape=[3,3,1,20])
   layer=tf.nn.conv2d(input=img,filter=w1,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
```

When I say "perfectly well" I mean the lines also run within a session to yield 
a numerical value of the layer. What is the difference between the two forms of statements?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d

input should be a tensorflow.Tensor, while you said that img is a greyscale image (I imagine converted into a numpy.ndarray).

You should either create a constant tensor with value your image, or a placeholder, and feed img as a value of the placeholder.

For example:

```
constant_img = tf.constant(img, shape=img.shape, dtype=tf.float32)
layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=constant_img, filter=w1,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
```

or

```
placeholder_img = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=img.shape)
layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=placeholder_img, filter=w1,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
```

in both cases, layer will be a tf.Tensor, so you won't see any numerical data. To extract numerical data you will have to open a session, and do something like

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

and then, in the first case (constant)

```
  layer_val = sess.run([layer])
```

while in the second case (placeholder)

```
  layer_val = sess.run([layer], feed_dict={placeholder_img: img})
```

Comment: Please see my modifications above

Comment: The point is that the input parameter of  tf.conv2d should be a tensorflow.Tensor, and not a numpy.ndarray

Comment: tf.conv2d runs perfectly well on np.array. As I wrote, I checked it. The only difference  between the two statements regrad to the definition of the filters. In  the first lines it is defined outside a function and in the other two lines it is defined without a function.

Comment: tf.conv2d runs perfectly well on np.array. As I wrote, I checked it. The only difference  between the two statements regrad to the definition of the filter w. In the first lines it is defined outside a function and in the other two lines it is defined within a function. Thats the whole difference.  Again, I run tf.nn.conv2d perefectly well on numpy array. I am sorry, but I do not understand your answers. I would like to understand why does it matter how do I define my filter. The problem is not with the input.  Or maybe I do not get something here.

Comment: there is a typo in the first line  w1=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3,3,1,20])    you miss a parenthesis, it that it?

Comment: Maybe, but python did not mention syntax error in this line. However, I copied again the lines from the respective functions where it worked well and this time the CNN run OK. That is, I probably did some syntax/dimension error. Sorry for this stupid question of mine and thank you for the time spending in revewing my code.